# ns3 please I have a qst about the instalation of ns3 I had this erreur , and I dont know how I can

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, qt

```
youx@youx:~$ sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev python-pygraphviz cvs mercurial bzr git cmake p7zip-full python-matplotlib python-tk python-dev python-kiwi python-gnome2 python-gnome2-desktop qt4-dev-tools qt4-qmake qt4-qmake qt4-default gnuplot-x11 wireshark
[sudo] password for youx: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for youx: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for youx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3

E: Unable to locate package python-pygraphviz
E: Unable to locate package python-matplotlib
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-kiwi
E: Unable to locate package python-gnome2
E: Unable to locate package python-gnome2-desktop
E: Unable to locate package qt4-dev-tools
E: Unable to locate package qt4-qmake
E: Unable to locate package qt4-qmake
E: Unable to locate package qt4-default
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

ns-3 is a discrete-event network simulator for internet systems,  targeted primarily for research and educational use.

To install ns3 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ns3
```

To install Python binding of ns3 in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-ns3
```